# NTP-client won't start with DHCPCD

Tags: linux, dhcp, services, ntp

The ntp-client service fails to start upon boot with a dynamic IP due to a name resolution problem. The server can be started upon boot completion manually and works fine. This is happening on multiple Linux Gentoo systems.

```
Sep 15 20:34:04 ns1 ntpdate[2442]: name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
Sep 15 20:34:04 ns1 /etc/init.d/ntp-client[2428]: ERROR: ntp-client failed to start
```

Comment: That's strange: don't you have a line like *After=network.target* in your ntpd.service file?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem with my Gentoo systems, especially the ones in virtual environments. For some reason the ntp-client is called too quickly after the network is started and at this moment DNS resolution does not work. I am able to resolve this issue by editing the /etc/init.d/ntp-client and adding the *sleep 5* line like this:

```
start() {
    checkconfig || return $?

    ebegin "Setting clock via the NTP client '${NTPCLIENT_CMD}'"
    sleep 5;
    "${NTPCLIENT_CMD}" ${NTPCLIENT_OPTS}
    eend $? "Failed to set clock"
}
```

5 seconds of sleep is the minimal time that works for me.